# Is there a nice way splitting a (potentially) long string without splitting in words in Python?

Tags: python, string, split, cpu-word, word-wrap

I want to make sure that I only print maximum 80 character long lines, but I have a string `s` that can be both shorter and longer than that. So I want to split it into lines *without* splitting any words.

Example of long string:

```
s = "This is a long string that is holding more than 80 characters and thus should be split into several lines. That is if everything is working properly and nicely and all that. No mishaps no typos. No bugs. But I want the code too look good too. That's the problem!"
```

I can devise ways of doing this such as:

```
words = s.split(" ")
line = ""
for w in words:
    if len(line) + len(w) <= 80:
        line += "%s " % w
    else:
        print line
        line ="%s " % w

print line
```

Equally I could use `s.find(" ")` iteratively in a while-loop:

```
sub_str_left = 0
pos = 0
next_pos = s.find(" ", pos)
while next_pos > -1:
    if next_pos - sub_str_left > 80:
        print s[sub_str_left:pos-sub_str_left]
        sub_str_left = pos + 1

    pos = next_pos
    next_pos = s.find(" ", pos)

print s[sub_str_left:]
```

None of these are very elegant, so my question is if there's a cooler pythonic way of doing this? (Maybe with regex or so.)

Comment: your question looks similar to question I asked few days ago.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9894983/wrapping-a-text-file-so-that-each-line-contain-a-maximum-of-80-characters

Comment: I missed that one searching for old posts, guess due to me looking for _splitting_ while it talked on _wrapping_, but yes they are similar.

Comment: well, technically this is called wrapping.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There's a module for that: [textwrap](http://docs.python.org/library/textwrap.html)

For instance, you can use

```
print '\n'.join(textwrap.wrap(s, 80))
```

or

```
print textwrap.fill(s, 80)
```

Answer (score 6):

```
import re
re.findall('.{1,80}(?:\W|$)', s)
```

Comment: This is a bad joke compared to basic word wrapping algorithms.

Comment: Not in terms of speed. Just benchmarked this against textwrap and it's about 50 times faster. (n.b. I know speed isn't everything, just interesting is all)

Comment: Speed is (nearly - you can still try changing the requirements) nothing if the functionality is lacking ;)

Answer (score 6):

```
import re

s = "This is a long string that is holding more than 80 characters and thus should be split into several lines. That is if everything is working properly and nicely and all that. No misshaps no typos. No bugs. But I want the code too look good too. That's the problem!"

print '\n'.join(line.strip() for line in re.findall(r'.{1,80}(?:\s+|$)', s))
```

**output:**

```
This is a long string that is holding more than 80 characters and thus should be
split into several lines. That is if everything is working properly and nicely
and all that. No misshaps no typos. No bugs. But I want the code too look good
too. That's the problem!
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this python script

```
import os, sys, re
s = "This is a long string that is holding more than 80 characters and thus should be split into several lines. That is if everything is working properly and nicely and all that. No misshaps no typos. No bugs. But I want the code too look good too. That's the problem!"
limit = 83
n = int(len(s)/limit)
b = 0
j= 0
for i in range(n+2):

    while 1:
        if s[limit - j] not in [" ","\t"]:
            j = j+1
        else:
            limit = limit - j
            break
    st = s[b:i*limit]
    print st
    b = i*limit
```