# Algorithms question about counting lines in a paragraph

Tags: python, string, algorithm, math

I'm having a little bit of trouble trying to figure out an efficient algorithm to solve this problem. You are given a long string
s="a bcd e f ghi j k lmn opq ghfdj ashks jahksjh jahkdaj jhakjd akjsdhka hskadjhka hkjdhak dkahsdkhsakjdhksah"

and a max line length integer maxLine = 6, which determines the max amount of characters in a line, how many lines would it take to fit the string

***you can't break up a string in the middle of a word****
for example:

input:

```
s="a bcd e f ghi j k lmn opq ghfdj ashks", maxLine = 6
```

line one:
a bcd

line two:
e f

line three:
ghi j

***I am trying to solve this algorithmically*** not with a package

Comment: You're breaking the word `ghi` across lines. You said you're not allowed to do that.

Comment: Does this answer help [Is there a nice way splitting a (potentially) long string without splitting word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9968173/is-there-a-nice-way-splitting-a-potentially-long-string-without-splitting-in-w)?  Answer suggests [textwrap module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/textwrap.html)

Comment: corrected error

Comment: "jahksjh" has 7 characters. What happens to this word?

Comment: it was a bad example, there shouldn't be any words longer than the length of the line

Comment: @darrylG I am trying to solve this algorithmically to find out how many lines it would take

Comment: So if we provide you with answers to this, are you going to post it to a coding challenge site and claim credit?

Comment: No, why would I do that, I am just trying to learn

Comment: Then write some code and  include it in your question to show what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a fairly efficient solution, it only requires a single pass over the string.

We track the start of the next line as `line_start_index`, then we iterate over each character and track the last space we saw as `line_end_index`.

Every time that we have iterated 6 characters from `line_start_index` we know that the next line is the substring `s[line_start_index:line_end_index]`. Then we set `line_start_index` to be the end of the previous line.

```
line_start_index = 0
line_end_index = 0
total = 0
for i, c in enumerate(s):
    if c == ' ':
        line_end_index = i
    if i - line_start_index == 6:
        # TODO: Handle words longer than 6 chars (line_start_index == line_end_index + 1)
        print('Found line!', s[line_start_index:line_end_index])
        total += 1
        line_start_index = line_end_index + 1

# For the data you have given there will be one additional line after the loop
# this may not be correct if the last char is a space
print('Found line!', s[line_start_index:])
total += 1
print(total)
```

This gives output:

```
Found line! a bcd
Found line! e f
Found line! ghi j
Found line! k lmn
Found line! opq
Found line! ghfdj
Found line! ashks
7
```

This won't work if there is a word longer than 6 chars but as you said there is no requirement to handle this

Answer (score 0):

A solution using a regex

```
>>> re.findall(r'\b.{1,6}\b', s)
['a bcd ', 'e f ', 'ghi j ', 'k lmn ', 'opq ', 'ghfdj ', 'ashks']
>>> len(_)
7
```

Comment: I am trying to solve this algorithmically not with a package